# rails 6 not loading javascript console log error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack

I am using Rails 6.0.2
When I open the browser console I get this error message:

*"Failed to load resource: the server responded application-c75873bc50757e62ae6f.js:1 with a status of 404 (Not Found)"*

In my layout template view the application.js file is loaded with the following tag:

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

This is my application.js file:

```
require("@rails/ujs").start();
require("turbolinks").start();
require("@rails/activestorage").start();
require("channels");
import "bootstrap";
```

Any suggestions to solve the issue?

Comment: Where is your application.js located?

Comment: app/javascript/packs/application.js   the file is located according to the default structure of a rails app